# gcc -x objective-c with Android SDK

Tags: android, objective-c, gcc, objective-c++

Since Objective-C exists and is supported even in MinGW, by passing `-x objective-c`, is there a hack to achieve this with Android SDK? I've did a rudimentary test on a colleague's machine where it appears that language `objective-c`is not supported.

I am not interested in getting UIKit or AppKit, or even Foundation, to work; I've written most of an OpenGLES game in Objective-C, and successfully ported it to Mac OS X and Windows; I am fairly certain I could easily port it to GNU/Linux once I get time to figure out enough of GNUStep (and even without it, I could create the classes to get the game running).

I'm just interested in the base language and basic runtime (including properties, if possible); even `NSObject` can be easily written to the extent I need it.

---

In the meantime, I've managed to compile some Objective-C code, and have written a guide for this:

- [Developing Objective-C apps for Android using Mac OS X](http://blog.vucica.net/2011/06/developing-objective-c-apps-for-android-using-mac-os-x.html)

There are more details in my answer below.

Comment: Heh, I love how someone downvoted the question probably, because of zealotry and not because it's uninteresting :)

Comment: There, I upvoted because it's directly applicable to my desire to get GDC, D language compiler support in the NDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to recompile the ndk gcc's sources with that option enabled.  At the extreme you might have to find the code for that option upstream and add it to the ndk gcc's sources.

Porting runtime libraries to work on top of bionic instead of glibc may be more interesting.

Note that android doesn't really handle pure-native binaries very well, you will need to either be called as a jni library from a java wrapper application which you will have to call back up through for audio or forked and exec'd off of one (not recommended, and leaving you with device-dependent hacks for audio).

Comment: That's somewhat too in-depth for me. I never liked recompiling GCC. I will accept, however, if you get a few upvotes from people more knowledgeable than me.

Answer (score 2):

The [Apportable platform](http://www.apportable.com/) includes a Clang compiler integration with the Android NDK. It also includes a bunch of other useful features if you want to go beyond basic Objective-C language and runtime support.

Answer (score 1):

There is this Google Code project: http://code.google.com/p/android-gcc-objc2-0/ however I have not tested it yet.

Also, I have inquired on the Cocotron mailing list whether or not this compiler is usable with Cocotron's Foundation and CoreFoundation; one person responded that it is not, and that he has worked on the problem: http://groups.google.com/group/cocotron-dev/browse_thread/thread/448355f2a6c9c28e#

---

<strike>In the meantime, I've managed to compile some Objective-C code, and have written a guide for this:</strike>

<strike>* [Developing Objective-C apps for Android using Mac OS X](http://blog.vucica.net/2011/06/developing-objective-c-apps-for-android-using-mac-os-x.html)</strike>

---

Clang is included in NDK nowadays if that's all you need.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Thanks, I performed an upgrade of the server and I never checked that a Wordpress plugin conflicted with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Nice doc.  There is also this NDK version that has GCC 4.6.3 in the toolchain: http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk